# Slider with map in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, dictionary, slider

I'm trying to make a slider using map but I don't know what went wrong.

The result of the image map should return a slider

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="pt-br">
    <head>

    
    </head>
    <body>
   <div id="slide">
 
          <div class="navigation">
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left prev-btn"></i>
            <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right next-btn"></i>
          </div>
         
          <div class="navigation-visibility">
            <div class="slide-icon active"></div>
            <div class="slide-icon"></div>
            <div class="slide-icon"></div>
            <div class="slide-icon"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>    
        <script>
          const initialSlides = [
            {
              description: <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>,
              Image: "../images/image1",
              button: <button class="slide">Veja</button>
            },
            {
              description: <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>,
              Image: '../images/image2',
              button: <button class="slide">Veja</button>
            },
            {
              description: <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>,
              Image: '../images/image3',
              button: <button class="slide">Veja</button>
            },
            {
              description: <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>,
              Image: '../images/image4',
              button: <button class="slide">Veja</button>
            },
          ];
    
          var resultadomap = initialSlides.map(function(slide, index){
              return '<div>
                          <img>${slide.Image}</img>
                          <p>${slide.description}</p>
                          <p>${slide.button}</p>
                        </div>';
    });
                  document.querySelector("#slide div").innerHTML = resultadomap.join("");
        </script>
    
      </div>
      </body>
    </html>
```

I'm trying to make a slider using map but I don't know what went wrong.

The result of the image map should return a slider

Comment: That is tons of invalid JavaScript syntax. This is wrong on so many levels. HTML is **NOT** allowed in JavaScript. I have no idea what you are expecting to happen.

Comment: Just put a ` around each string, for start

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "she was trying to reproduce it", but the code in the fiddle looks _a lot_ better.

Comment: Sorry for doing such a stupid thing. I was trying to reproduce it. https://jsfiddle.net/xvt6wbvb/

Answer (score 2):

```css
body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

#slide .navigation {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
      -ms-flex-pack: justify;
          justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  height: 40vh;
}

#slide .navigation i {
  font-size: 50px;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: black;
  padding: 2%;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

#slide .navigation i:first-of-type {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}

#slide .navigation i:last-of-type {
  position: relative;
  top: 40%;
}

#slide .navigation-visibility {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
}

#slide .navigation-visibility .show {
  display: block !important;
}

#slide .navigation-visibility .hide {
  display: none;
}

#slide .navigation-visibility .sliderItem {
  display: -webkit-box !important;
  display: -ms-flexbox !important;
  display: flex !important;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
      -ms-flex-direction: column;
          flex-direction: column;
}

#slide .navigation-visibility img {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Array</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="slide">

      <div class="navigation">
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-left" id="prev-btn"></i>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-arrow-right" id="next-btn"></i>
      </div>

      <div class="navigation-visibility">
        <!-- <div class="slide-icon active"></div>
        <div class="slide-icon"></div>
        <div class="slide-icon"></div>
        <div class="slide-icon"></div> -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- </div>     -->

    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/7f8c2c17fa.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>
      let initialSlides = [
        {
          description: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.`,
          Image: "https://preview.redd.it/yc40cow4tr691.png?auto=webp&s=0634e4b596dec75e35a2e138eac1ee075ffdd910",
          button: `<button class="slide">Veja</button>`,
          active: true
        },
        {
          description: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.`,
          Image: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0573/7522/8070/products/OP-428-Frankyjpg.jpg?v=1622780043',
          button: `<button class="slide">Veja</button>`,
          active: false
        },
        {
          description: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.`,
          Image: 'https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/0573/7522/8070/products/OP-408usa.jpg?v=1636850709',
          button: `<button class="slide">Veja</button>`,
          active: false
        },
        {
          description: `Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. labore et dolore magna aliqua.`,
          Image: 'https://i.pinimg.com/originals/53/39/a6/5339a63c4ce03123bb21a2131e0099ae.jpg',
          button: `<button class="slide">Veja</button>`,
          active: false
        },
      ];

      const ShowInitialSlid = (slideData) => {
        var resultadomap = slideData.map(function(slide, index) {
            return `
            <div class="${slide.active ? 'show sliderItem' : 'hide'}">
                <img src="${slide.Image}" />
                <p>${slide.description}</p>
                ${slide.button}
            </div>
            `;
        });
        document.querySelector("#slide .navigation-visibility").innerHTML = resultadomap.join("");
      }

      ShowInitialSlid(initialSlides)

      document.querySelector("#next-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let currentIndex = initialSlides.findIndex(el => el.active == true)

        if(initialSlides.length - 1 != currentIndex) {
            initialSlides[currentIndex].active = false
            initialSlides[currentIndex + 1].active = true
        }
        else {
            initialSlides[initialSlides.length - 1].active = false
            initialSlides[0].active = true
        }

        ShowInitialSlid(initialSlides)  
      })
      document.querySelector("#prev-btn").addEventListener("click", () => {
        let currentIndex = initialSlides.findIndex(el => el.active == true)

        if(currentIndex != 0) {
            initialSlides[currentIndex].active = false
            initialSlides[currentIndex - 1].active = true
        }
        else {
            initialSlides[0].active = false
            initialSlides[initialSlides.length - 1].active = true
        }

        ShowInitialSlid(initialSlides)
      })

    </script>

  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was trying to put autoplay with the following code: '`counter = 0
          const setImage = () => {
          document.getElementById("slider").src = initialSlides[counter];
          counter = (counter+1)  % initialSlides.length;
          }

          setInterval(setImage, 2000);`